# How to save images witch Dialogflow and N8N

Tags: automated-tests, dialogflow-es, n8n

I have a project, and I need to save the images that the user sends me via WhatsApp. The context of the project is that my "robot" prompts the user to send me a photo of a document, and I need to save this image in a local folder or upload it to Google Drive.

However, my problem is that when the user sends me a photo, the system returns the message " Photo." This example is from another project that uses Google Sheets. I'm using the same logic because I'm still in the early stages of studying these automations, and my first project with spreadsheets worked very well.

But when it comes to collecting images from WhatsApp, I haven't found anything on the web that can help me with this.

I searched a bit, but I couldn't find solutions that don't involve using paid WhatsApp APIs to collect this information. I'm in need of a solution that utilizes DialogFlow and N8N or any other free alternative to collect the image directly in the user's conversation.

For those who are unsure about how it works, essentially, I use DialogFlow for interactions, N8N for workflow management, and a mobile app called "auto reply" that uses the Dialog JSON to respond automatically.